# Provider with httpclient call returns undefined in the first try ( Ionic 5 / Angular )

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my service I'm trying to get data from my backend, when I click on the button for the first try it returns undefined, but on the second try everything works fine, someone have any suggestions that would fix this for me.

my provider function is below:

```
getArtisants(){
this.HttpClient.get('http://localhost/AlloMealem/backend/web/index.php?r=artisant/all').
        subscribe(result => {
            this.artisans=result;
        });
        return this.artisans;
    }
```

My service function that gets the data from the provider and put it in an array so I can use it in my components

```
 getArtisants() {
    this._artisans=this.searchProvider.getArtisants();
 } 
}
```

I expect to get my data in the first try because some of my pages should get data in the onInit() function which makes it important to get data in the first try.

Comment: return this.artisans; this line is causing it to return undefined initially as it is not waiting for subscribe to finish

Comment: @user8351493 what do suggest to change. I not that familiar with Ionic.
Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation. You are doing wrong things here. Your service should return a observable, and in the component you should subscribe. First of all this is asynchronous, secondly you cannot return from subscribe: https://angular.io/guide/http and also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Check for `platform.ready()` and then invoke you http plugin , Platform ready promise will make sure all the plugins are loaded before you attempt to call them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this 
return an observable and then subscribe in calling function

````
getArtisants(){
return this.HttpClient.get('http://localhost/AlloMealem/backend/web/index.php?r=artisant/all')

    }

 getArtisants() {
   this.searchProvider.getArtisants().subscribe((res)=> { this._artisans=res;});
 } 
    ```

I have not used Ionic but hoping it will be similar to Angular
````

Comment: is it still getting undefined?

Comment: Yes still getting it

Comment: can you create a small example on stackblitz with the same issue?

Comment: I'm trying to do it !! it's the first time I use stackblitz, it's a bit strange for me